# append date time stamp issue to filename in unix script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have bunch of files that are generated by legacy system and the requirment is to rename the files to long description (something business users can understand).

Sample file name: `bususrapp.O16200.L1686.1201201304590298`

RptList: `bususrapp Billing file for app user`

when the system generates a file 'bususrapp' file, this will be translated to 'Billing file for app user' and the final output need to be 
something like "**Billing file for app user.1201201304590298.txt**"

```
for i in `ls * `;  do j=`grep $i /tmp/Rptlist | awk '{print $2 $3 $4 $5} ;'` mv $i $j;  done
```

The last qualifier in the sample file is my date&time stamp. I need to cut/copy and append it to the new long description file name. "**Billing file for app user.1201201304590298.txt**"

Please suggest how to achive this.

Comment: What is the value of `$i`? If it contains the full filename, how does that return any results from the `grep` part?

Comment: Never loop over the results from `ls` like that. Use the glob directly. `for i in *; ...; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you want.

```
for file in *; do
    # Drop everything up to the last .
    stamp=${fname##*.};

    # Drop everything after the first period.
    name=${fname%%.*}

    # Find the matching line in RptList.
    line=$(grep "$name" RptList)
    # Drop the first (space separated) field.
    line=${line#* }

    outfile="$line.$stamp.txt"

    mv $file $outfile;
done
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answer. Etan's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Give your input file, this awk will make your desired output filename:

```
echo "bususrapp.O16200.L1686.1201201304590298 RptList: bususrapp Billing file for app user" | awk -F"[.]| RptList| bususrapp " '{print $NF"." $4 ".txt"}'
Billing file for app user.1201201304590298.txt
```

Use `FS` to do all of the hard work and then print the fields the fields out in your specified order.

---

Here's a more complete answer:

```
# use find instead of ls, pointing to files only
find /tmp/Rptlist -name "bususrapp*" -type f -print |
awk -F/ '
    {
    # rebuild the path which was split up by FS
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++) path = path $i"/"
    fname=$NF

    # split up the file name for recombination
    c=split(fname, a, "[.]| RptList:| bususrapp ")

    # output 2 arguments the "/original/file/path" "/new/file/path"
    printf( "\"%s%s\" \"%s%s.%s.txt\"\n", path, fname, path, a[c], a[4] )
    path=""
    }' |
# use xargs to feed those two arguments to mv for the copy
xargs -n2 mv
```

Just a different style.  @EtanReisner 's answer is cleaner.  Since I don't script in bash, this is what I would have tried.

Comment: You can use `awk ' .... ' <<< "bususrapp..."` also. It helps to see the `awk` command first.